# Plotting a complex function

Tags: plotting, functions, warning-messages, complex

What does it mean if this message appears:

> {Im[(1-E^Times[<<3>>] f)/(1-Power[<<2>>] f)]-0,Im[(1-E^Times[<<3>>] f)/(1-Power[<<2>>] f)]-0} must be a list of equalities or real-valued functions. >>

while Iam trying to plot this complex function

```
(I α)/π (Log[(1 - E^(-((I π(1 - α))/α)) f) / (1 - E^((I π(1 - α))/α) f)])
```

How can I plot this function for the range {α, 0.1, 1} and {f, 0.2, 1}?

#### Edit

Corrected errors in the expression to be plotted.

Comment: Something is really messed up here, can you cleanup the expression?

Comment: Can you provide the mathematical problem itself?

Comment: The factor `π[1 - α]` in your expression is a function call in _Mathematica_. Did you mean `π(1 - α)`?

Comment: Could you post the entire `Plot` expression you tried?

Comment: 1-(I[Alpha])/[Pi](Log[(
    1 - E^(-((I[Pi][1-[Alpha]])/[Alpha]))f)/(
    1 - E^((I[Pi][1-[Alpha]])/[Alpha])f)])

Comment: m_goldberg  yes that is what I mean

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

for the real part of the expression

```
ContourPlot[Re[(I α)/π(Log[(1 - E^(-((I π (1 - α))/α))f)/(1 - E^((I π (1 - α))/α)f)])], 
            {α, 0.1,1}, {f, .2, 1}]
```

> [image]

for the imaginary part of the expression

```
ContourPlot[Im[(I α)/π(Log[(1 - E^(-((I π (1 - α))/α))f)/(1 - E^((I π (1 - α))/α)f)])], 
            {α, 0.1,1}, {f, .2, 1}]
```

> [image]

If you simplify the expression using `ComplexExpand` you will find out that this is is in fact a real function

$$
-\frac{\alpha  \text{Arg}\left[\frac{1+e^{-\frac{i \pi }{\alpha }} f}{1+e^{\frac{i \pi }{\alpha }} f}\right]}{\pi }
$$

Using this instead its `Plot3D` is:

> [image]

Comment: thank u very much but may I have the 2D Plotting of the function plz?

Comment: @sana the function depends on two variables so it defines a surface in 3D. In 2D you can have its contour plot which I have given in the first plot.

Comment: understood now.. thank you again